# WPF ListView no scrollbar if height set to auto

Tags: wpf, listview, layout, scrollbar

Hi i have a ListView that binds to a collection. I set the height of the ListView to auto for it to take up all the space in the region. However there is not scrollbar after i set the height to auto. If i give it a height then the scrollbar would show up.

the markup is pretty much like the following

```
<Grid>
   <StackPanel>
      <Expander>
          <DataGrid>
      <Expander>
          <ListView>
```

Comment: I have a hunch that "any thoughts?" isn't your actual question here.

Comment: What kind of container/panel is the `ListView` inside?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I have a hunch that your `ListView` is inside a panel that allows it to expand vertically without limit.

If you put a `ListView` inside a `StackPanel`, for example, the `ListView`'s height can exceed the height of the `StackPanel`. The `ListView` has increased its height to show all its items, as far as it's concerned, thus no scrollbar.

However, if you change that `StackPanel` to a `Grid`, where controls automatically try to fit themselves inside that area, the `ListView` will automatically have a scrollbar when it contains more items than it can display.

This will probably be solved most simply by adjusting your layout that contains the `ListView`.

Comment: that's exactly what I have here. Updated the post with markup sample.

Comment: I would ask: Are the 2 `Expanders` the only things in the `StackPanel`? Is the `StackPanel` the only things in the `Grid`? Do you want the `ListView` to only take up as much room as is available in the outer `Grid`? If all those are *yes*, you could use a `DockPanel` instead of a `StackPanel`. If the `Expander` with the `ListView` is the last child, it will fill the remaining area.

Comment: Excellent explanation Joel. Helped me solve a similar problem where I had placed a ListView inside a StackPanel.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of setting

```
<RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
```

set:

```
<RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
```

Comment: Um, did you mean to refer to the `Height` Property on one or more of the *`Row`*'s of the `Grid`'s?  AFAIK, of all the Elements mentioned, the *`Row`*'s of the `Grid`'s are the only Elements whose `Height` Property accepts "*" notation.

Answer (score 4):

Why should it show a scrollbar if there is nothing to scroll?

If you want to override any default behavior you can set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` on the ListBox.