# How do I get a scrollbar to appear with a ListView when the height is auto?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm working on a Windows Store App.

I have a ListView with a bunch of items in it. It is nested in some stack panels and grids, but they all essentially are auto sized. Essentially, the ListView is given most of the right half of the screen, regardless of what size it is.

If I give the ListView a hard-valued Height, a scrollbar will automatically appear with no extra work. Great. But I don't want to set a height... I want it to be all of the area available in its container. If I try to be clever and set it to 9999 or something then it will not scroll.

I've done a bunch of research, and similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221813/wpf-listview-no-scrollbar-if-height-set-to-auto) say that the thing that holds the ListView cannot give it infinite size like a StackPanel would. What alternatives do I have? How can I put a ListView in something with arbitrary space and get a scroll bar to appear?

My only thought is that there must be some way to, in the container that holds the ListView, tell the ListView that it has all available area in such a way that it's height gets set that that value. Sort of like how to have to set ListViewItem's HorizontalContentAlignment property to 'Stretch' in order to get the items within a ListView to know what what available width they actually have.

The essential bits of my layout is this:

```
<!-- Nested in some other stuff simple Grids and StackPanels, none of which has hard heights set (all auto or *) -->

<!-- Even if I made this a Grid with one Row, setting definition to * or Auto doesn't help the issue - no scroll bar appears -->
<StackPanel>

    <!-- Other stuff that has Visibility="Collapsed"... I have code so that only one item at a time within this container will ever be visible, and it gets all available space. -->

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeBigList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />

    <!-- Other stuff that has Visibility="Collapsed" -->

</StackPanel>
```

How can I get a scrollbar to appear in the ListView without setting a hard height anywhere? Thanks for you're help.

Comment: Stackpanel always sizes to the minimum size needed to contain its children (I.e it wont fill the parent container). You could just use several nested grids with * size as the children would take up all space without being given infinite size

Comment: have you tried switching the `StackPanel` to a `DockPanel` and then in the `ListView` set `Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DockPanel}}, Path=ActualHeight}"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a `<StackPanel>`.

If you are in control over what gets drawn and only one item is ever visible at any one time, then use a non-infinite sized container like `<Grid>`. You can put each item in the same row, or use a separate row if only for ease of spotting what's what.

Comment: Going to 100% grids does fix the issue, even if it is in a * sized row. I wish that StackPanels had a knob to make them not infinite sized or something. So far it has been such an intuitive container, I hate dismissing it for the slightly more verbose grid.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar on the Windows Phone app. You need to remove the variables of the other containers by creating a test page and determining which panel is causing your ultimate problem.

1. Create new blank page with a Grid and ListView.
2. Work the grid sizing to be automatic (auto) or * sized until you see the horizontal scroll bar.
3. Once the horizontal scroll bar appears, add the other containers, one by one until the scroll bar disappears. That will inform you of the culprit which is causing the miss-sizing and ultimately the failure of the scrollbar to appear.