# How appear VerticalScrollBar in resize window in ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollbar

```
<UserControl x:Class="PMS.UserControlUsersList"
//...
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PMS"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>


    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
                <Expander Grid.Row="0" Header="Filters" Margin="10" Background="White" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <Grid>
                       //...
                    </Grid>
                </Expander>

            <ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredUsers}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" Header="First name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" Width="Auto"/>
                        <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" Header="Last name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" Width="Auto"/>

//other GridViewColum


                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>

        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Hello. When I resize window VerticalScrollBar in ListView doesn't appear.
HorizontalScrollBar works fine. How I can fix this? 
When I set MaxHeight VerticalScrollBar is visible but this isn't good solution :P

UserControl is placing in StackPanel:

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelMain" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      <!-- my UserControl is here -->
 </StackPanel>
```

Edit:
Look how it looks with me. UserControl is displayed in the bottom right corner. On the left is a menu and a bar at the top. In the main window I use WindowStyle = "None".

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tqjD.png)

[It's good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0IdS.png)

Here, I pasted the full Window and Usercontrol code: [full code](https://pastebin.pl/view/0868f489)

Comment: Your code sample you provided by your link is missing the usage of your `UserControl`. The most obvious reason of your issue is that you are placing your `UserControl` to wrong panel container. Please clarify your question with minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: UserControl is placing in StackPanel: <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelMain" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

Comment: StackPanelMain.Children.Clear();
StackPanelMain.Children.Add(userControl);

Comment: please put this info to your question as it is probably the key to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing your nested `ListView` inside a `StackPanel`, which prevents it from calculating its size properly. Instead, your control renders to invisible area thus not showing a vertical scrollbar.

Consider changing your container panel to `Grid`.

See also: [WPF ListView no scrollbar if height set to auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221813/wpf-listview-no-scrollbar-if-height-set-to-auto)

Comment: I edit line: "<Grid x:Name="StackPanelMain" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>" I changed StackPanel and work fine :) Thanks!